# How to run Flex samples

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

Well, this is embarrassing. I want to get into Flex development but I'm having problems even opening up sample Flex projects! (I'm running on Snow Leopard and trying to use Flash Builder 4)

Here are the projects that I was looking at: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/samples.html

I downloaded a sample project.. but couldn't find anything to open! There was an `mxml` file that OS X just wasn't going to let me open. I had to change the extension to `xml` to see the contents of the file.

I did finally manage to get the project open and loaded. I created a new Flex project in Flash Builder 4, added a `swc` file to my `libs` directory, and replaced the content of the `mxml` and `xml` files with what I downloaded. That compiled fine and I was able to run the project.

Surely, there's an easier way of opening sample projects... right? But, doing a bit of searching, I found [this tutorial](http://www.wonderhowto.com/how-to-run-adobe-flex-project-from-google-code-255448/)... and he basically did the same thing I did. I hate to whine, but having to do all this to open a sample project..?

Hopefully someone here will tell me there's a friendlier, easier way of doing this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to File -> Import FlashBuilder Project.  Select "Project Folder", and point it to the folder that is the root (the one that includes the src folder).

It should load up with no problem.  Press the Run button.  It should compile and run.

Sometimes, code is shipped as an FXP, which is really just a zipped up folder.  When you open it with File -> Import FlashBuilder Project and Select "file", it unzips the files into a folder and opens it the same way.

Good luck!
Brian